# Trying to auto-move 'Via' spam from Spam folder to trash in my Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, spam, email-spam

So, guess I'm odd or something. I dun like to even see any spam in my spam folder. AT ALL. As in, I want that folder to only occasionally get something due to an error on the sender's behalf, or just nothing there. I like to keep things tidy, I suppose. However, these days, I keep getting spam with this annoying 'via' tag, and there's just no way to filter those addresses, like... no-reply@zeazpokjyelp.bodeel.delicorunni.eu or something like contact@vjtsk.hazydragon.bg.caughtupinyourthoughts.com.

They just randomize it over and over again, but, they have -one- thing in common. They are -all- sent 'via mydns.jp' [A few random other addresses before it, but, the root of it is that 'myDNS' address.]

I would create a filter, and tell it to block anything from said forwarding address... but, as I am painfully aware, it seems Google doesn't have that function in it's blocking feature.

So, I tried to make something on my own, however, that's built to move junk mail from the INBOX to TRASH. Google already knows it's spam, and is labeled/moved into the Spam folder, I just dun wanna see it at all, and do not pass go, do not collect $200, just go to the trash.

I tried to edit the script found here; https://www.geektron.com/2014/01/how-to-filter-gmail-using-email-headers-and-stop-via-spam/ but, again, that's built to move mail from my Inbox to my Spam. I dun wanna see it at all.

```
function filterViaSpam() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getSpamThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message=messages[j];
      var body=message.getRawContent();
      if(body.indexOf("X-Forwarded-For: *@*.mydns.jp")>-1){
        GmailApp.moveThreadToTrash(threads[i]);
      }
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

..well, nothing happens. Guess the script doesn't see any emails, but they exist in my Spam folder.

Per request, I logged the output. This is what I got:

```
[19-07-19 03:31:47:424 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:48:797 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:50:186 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:51:516 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:52:943 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:54:252 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:55:598 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:56:970 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:58:304 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:31:59:698 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:01:001 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:02:358 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:03:673 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:05:062 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:06:411 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:07:731 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:09:087 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:10:390 PDT] -1.0
[19-07-19 03:32:11:678 PDT] -1.0
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code? Try: `Logger.log(body.indexOf("X-Forwarded-For: *@*.mydns.jp"));` and show the log in your question.

Comment: ..um.. I might let ya know now I'm a novice at this, and with little to no time to do this [Read; generally work 84 hour work weeks...] With that said... how do I do this?

Comment: On the line under your `var body` insert the code I gave you. Run your function then go to `View > Logs`, copy and paste the log entries to your question.

Comment: Updated as requested; sorry for the delay.

Comment: The issue lies with your `body.indexOf()`, it's not finding any matches to the string you've provided.

Comment: O... kay. Um... any way to fix it? Thanks for your help thus far, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Expecting wildcards  like `*` to work with `indexOf`: `indexOf()` receives a plain string as argument and doesn't support wildcards.

#### Solution:

- Use regular expressions: Methods like `String#match`, `Regexp#test` support regex as argument.

#### Snippet:

```
if(/X\-Forwarded\-For: .*?@.*?\.mydns\.jp/.test(body)){
```

#### References:

- [Regexp#test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [String#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Thanks for your input... however, I replaced the line as suggested... but, nothing happens still. Am I missing something?

Comment: So... the addresses I am trying to move are in the 'Mailed via' fields, and they come from like, 20+ different variations of mydns.jp... is there just no way to tell it to move anything coming from that address at all?

Comment: I mean, like I have one from info@tnt.car.srvce.mydns.jp and another from osos.296i74@locu.viernes.mydns.jp .. actually, it seems those two are it, for the moment. Both end with the *.mydns.jp. And Google says [random email address here] via those two sites. So, even if I were to keep ahead of the randomly generated email addresses.

Comment: @Hazy Try the previous codes. `if(/mydns\.jp/.test(body)){` should work.

Comment: That's a thing of beauty. Watching my spam folder get smaller and smaller. Thanks!

Comment: Now, if I wanted to add another site, say, from us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com do I just add a new line with the same code, or...?

Comment: @Hazy There is a OR used in if `||` like `if((condition1) || ( condition2)){}`. Then there's a OR  used in regex `|` like ``if(/(mydns\.jp)|(east\-2\.compute\.amazonaws\.com)/.test(body)){}``. Please test the regex @ https://regex101.com you can see the explanations  there too. Also search for JavaScript operators.

Comment: That's all I needed, thanks! I needed to lock onto the pattern provided, and bamn! All the via addys I can find are added to that list. Thanks a ton, been struggling ever since I applied online, like an idiot, for car insurance. Thanks a lot!